# Selecionar registro mais recente de determinada tabela - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Preciso selecionar o registro mais recente de minha `Estoque` caso a coluna `data` seja diferente, consegui da seguinte forma trazer o mais antigo quando as datas são diferentes:

```
SELECT codigosuprimento, numeroserie, max(data)
FROM public.estoque where usado = '1' and numeroserie = '1201607048733' 
group by codigosuprimento, numeroserie;
```

Porém quando a coluna `data` for igual quero que ele traga todos os registros que as datas sejam iguais, por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Traria as duas linha já que as datas são iguais, mas quando for assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Iria trazer o da data `2017-08-18` por ser a mais atual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma solução pode ser um subselect com MAX

```
SELECT codigosuprimento, numeroserie, data
FROM public.estoque p1----faz uma primeira instancia da tabela 
where usado = '1' 
and numeroserie = '1201607048733' 
-- este subselect procura a maior data da mesma chave do registro
and data = (SELECT max(data)
            --faz uma segunda instancia da tabela 
            --renomeia o "alaias" para diferenciar
            FROM public.estoque p2
            where p2.usado       = p1.usado
            and   p2.numeroserie = p1.numeroserie)
```

Comment: Deu certo :) Poderia só me explicar como funcionou seu `select`? Assim que liberar já marco como correta a resposta

Comment: Só uma questão, tentei executar esse comando sem a restrição de um numero de serie definido e ficou carregando e me retornou algo depois de algum tempo processando, na questão de processamento tu saberia algo que consumisse menos quem sabe?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Tem uns 10.000 registros mais ou menos, a questão de índice na tabela data como assim índice?

Comment: roda o seguinte comando: `CREATE INDEX estoque_data_idx ON public.estoque
  USING btree (data DESC);` ele vai indexar a coluna para agilizar a pesquisa. Veja o tempo de retorno da consulta em ambos os casos e posta aí o resultado

Comment: @RovannLinhalis depois de criar o `index` o tempo de resposta foi mais rápido mesmo, demorou um pouco ainda mas menos do que antes, obrigado

Comment: Só uma questão referente a isso, caso eu queira deletar os dados que possuem datas inferiores ao invés de só trazer os mais atuais como poderia fazer isso?

Comment: @R.Santos aí você tem que ver, vai precisar desse registro ainda ? é inútil ? apaga. Mas pensando por esse lado, talvez o certo fosse atualizar a data e não apagar um registro e inserir outro com os mesmos dados. Não entendi qual o proposito de uma tabela de estoque com esses dados, mas ok.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67942/discussion-between-r-santos-and-rovann-linhalis).

Comment: Sem a restrição de número de séria se cai quase com certeza em um "full table scan".