# Relacionamento com tabela de log

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Galera, beleza?

Eu tenho duas tabelas de um banco oracle:
Campos da Tabela A:

```
No. do chamado
Data de conclusão do chamado
Funcionario que concluiu
```

Campos da Tabela B:

```
Funcionario
Area do funcionario
Data da alteracao da area
```

Eu preciso relacionar via PL/SQL as duas tabelas de modo que resultem na tabela abaixo:
Campos da Tabela C:

```
A.No. do chamado
A.Data de conclusão do chamado
A.Funcionario que concluiu
B.Area do funcionario
```

O problema é que de todas as formas que tentei juntar as duas tabelas, quando o funcionario passou por uma alteração, o relacionamento tem retornado todas as areas que o funcionario passou, se teve 3 alterações, acabo tendo algo do tipo:
No. do chamado | Data de conclusao do chamado | Funcionario que concluiu | Area do funcionario

```
######9 | 11/09/2020 | Fulano de tal | Area Z
######9 | 11/09/2020 | Fulano de tal | Area y
######9 | 11/09/2020 | Fulano de tal | Area X
######8 | 22/08/2019 | Fulano de tal | Area Z
######8 | 22/08/2019 | Fulano de tal | Area Y
######8 | 22/08/2019 | Fulano de tal | Area X
######7 | 03/05/2017 | Fulano de tal | Area Z
######7 | 03/05/2017 | Fulano de tal | Area Y
######7 | 03/05/2017 | Fulano de tal | Area X
```

Porem o que eu preciso é:

```
######9 | 11/09/2020 | Fulano de tal | Area Z
######8 | 22/08/2019 | Fulano de tal | Area Y
######7 | 03/05/2017 | Fulano de tal | Area X
```

Alguem poderia me ajudar? Realmente não consegui pensar em uma lógica de PL/SQL que retorne o resultado correto. Lembrando que a data de alteração e a data de conclusão não são necessariamente iguais.

Obrigado!!!

Comment: E por qual motivo você escolhe a Area Z e não a Area X ou a Area Y? Você tem que definir este critério.

Comment: Qual o crítério ? Não é a maior data ,  o 2017 da área X na segunda sáida saiu da cartola pelo visto ...

Comment: @Motta não saiu da cartola, foi só mais uma linha de exemplo do que poderia vir no resultado...

Comment: @anonimo o critério é que a pessoa que respondeu o chamado em 2019 trabalhava na area Y, mas por movimentação interna, em 2020 essa pessoa foi para a area Z. Mas a tabela A, que armazena a informação do funcionário que encerrou o chamado, só armazena o código da área atual, de modo que, se eu só considerar essa tabela, todos os chamados do passado estarão associados à área atual

Comment: Não sei se é claro o suficiente, mas acho que a situação é mais ou menos essa: Se a data de conclusão do chamado é anterior a uma movimentação, associar à área anterior à movimentação. Se maior, mas menor que a última movimentação, a associar à área correspondente ao intervalo. Se após a última movimentação, associar a área após última movimentação. Um funcionário pode ter N movimentações ao logo do tempo.

Comment: Estas regras não garantem unicidade , já tentou obter a maior movimentação ? um exemplo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/251198/selecionar-registro-mais-recente-de-determinada-tabela-postgresql

Comment: @Motta tudo bem? Já tentei sim, nos casos de 2 movimentações resolve, mas nos casos com mais de duas movimentações continuo com intervalos de tempo associando o funcionário à área errada. Vou tentar esse fazer relacionando em uma ferramenta externa de visualização de dados, utilizando mais de uma consulta ao banco e criando campos calculados na ferramenta.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se resolvi da melhor forma, mas para os casos que testei, funcionou utilizando a seguinte consulta:

```
with
chamadotroca as (
                  select
                        a.No_do_chamado as chamado,
                        a.Data_conclusao_chamado as encerramento,
                        a.funcionario_concluiu as funcionario,
                        max(b.Data_alteracao) as troca
                  from
                        tabelaA a,
                        tabelaB b
                  where
                        a.funcionario_concluiu = b.funcionario
                        and b.Data_alteracao < a.Data_conclusao_chamado 
                  group by a.No_do_chamado ,
                        a.Data_conclusao_chamado,
                        a.funcionario_concluiu,
                  order by 2 desc, 5 desc
                )
select
      ct.chamado as chamado,
      ct.encerramento as encerramento,
      ct.funcionario as funcionario,
      b.area_funcionario AS area,
      ct.troca
from
      chamadotroca ct,
      tabelaB b
where
      ct.funcionario = b.funcionario
      and ct.troca = b.trca_dh_registro
```